# PHP - How to show POST elaboration result clicking previous page button and not refreshing page

Tags: php, post, refresh, back

I'm developing a php page that is the result of some php elaboration with parameters in taken from POST values.
When I go to the next page and go back to the page that I'm developing, the browser asks me again to POST the data reloading the entire page. My problem isn't related to the multiple post request, but I want only to show page. What can I do this? Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this steps:

1) Save result of some php elaboration into session.
2) After POST request is submitted and result saved to session, redirect user to other page which will display the result.
3) On those page where user inputs data, clear the session storage before processing submitted data.

So, in fact you need something that is usually called 'Session messages stack'.

Comment: i like this solution.. simple and useful.. i'll try it now! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Post/Redirect/Get (PRG) Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).

Comment: I said exactly the same. And pure Post/Redirect/Get (PRG) Pattern will not help him is the result is too complicated to put it into $_GET params. But I won't downvote.

Comment: I understand what you  mean. But is it too complicated to pass values from one array ($_POST) to another array ($_GET) and pass it to url ?

Comment: No, he means not to pass $_POST. He means to pass the result of calculations based on $_POST (As I understand). And who knows what is that result.. Maybe longer tha $_GET request max length...

Comment: Agree. $_GET has its own length limit.